# Catcode change for command arguments

Tags: beamer, macros, catcodes

I want to write commands that can have arguments within <> by changing the catcode of the two signs.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[3]{
This is #1. This is #2. This is #3.
}
\catcode`<=1
\catcode`>=2

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\mycommand<text 1>{text 2}<text 3>
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This does not work. How can the catcode be changed correctly? Or are there other methods to make such a command readable without using extra packages?

Comment: This is a _really_ bad idea in `beamer`, as `<..>` has specific meaning. What's the reason for needing to use tokens other than `{`/`}`?

Comment: Yes, I would only want to change it temporary. I wanted to create Commands like Beamer has them, but with multiple arguments in <> (combining it with recursion the amount of arguments can be variable).

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do: assuming the category code assignment works, you can make your call with `\mycommand<text 1><text 2><text 3>` or `\mycommand{test 1}<test 2>{test 3}` or any variation thereof. And breaking all overlay options of `beamer` doesn't seem a good price to pay.

Comment: you do not want to change the catcode of < and > that has a completely different effect to the effect that you say you want (which is beamer-like behaviour) if you make them 1 and 2 then they can be used everywhere and are indistinguishable from {}  so you could use `\frac<a>{2}`  or even `\frac<1}{2>`  or `\begin{enumerate>`  is that really what you intend????

Comment: beamer's <>. like normal optional argument delimiters [] are catcode 12.

Comment: My plan was to change catcode right before calling the command and changing it back afterwards. Adding a recursion will allow the command to process `\myrecursivecommand<>{}`or `\myrecursivecommand<>{}<>{}` by calling `\mycommand` as often as arguments are there.

Comment: You really do not want to do this,

Comment: don't you want to distinguish arguments marked with `<arg>` from those marked with `{arg}` ?  That is virtually impossible if you make <> have catcode 1 and 2

Comment: I am calling two arguments at a time and I would just assume the first of each two to be <>. I am no expert with this, but I have not found a better way yet.

Comment: no if you make < catcode 1 you can use `\begin<document}` it means < really is a { for almost all uses. so without any definition at all all latex commands would accept arguments delimited by < but treat them the same way as if they were delimited with {  It will completely break beamer as it will no longer be able to see its  catcode 12 <> delimiters

Comment: What about arguments, where matching pairs of `<` and `>` are nested, e.g., `\mycommand<<te><xt>< 1>>{text 2}<<text 3>>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the catcode setting after `\begin{document}` because `beamer` enforces the catcode of `<` and `>` at `\begin{document}` (changing catcodes in the preamble is problematic anyway).  You can do:

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \catcode`<=1\relax
  \catcode`>=2\relax}
```

Though you will probably break a lot of `beamer` by changing the catcode of `<` and `>`, since `beamer` expects those to be catcode-12. I'd suggest you instead load `xparse` and use delimited arguments, so you don't have to change catcodes:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\mycommand{r<>mr<>}{%
  This is #1. This is #2. This is #3.%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\mycommand<text 1>{text 2}<text 3>
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

And with `xparse` you can make the `<...>` arguments optional (as they usually are in `beamer`) by using `d<>` instead of `r<>` in the command signature.  With that you can check that the `d` argument was given and make a recursive call.

In the code below, if `\mycommand` is called without a `<...>`-delimited argument, it does nothing.  Otherwise it calls `\mycommmandaux` which takes the `<...>`-delimited argument, plus a mandatory (delimited by `{...}`) and prints the text, then calls `\mycommand` again to look for more.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\mycommand{d<>}{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{\mycommandaux{#1}}}
\NewDocumentCommand\mycommandaux{mm}{%
   This is #1. This is #2. \mycommand}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\mycommand<text 1>{text 2}

\mycommand<text 1>{text 2}<text 3>{text 4}<text 5>{text 6}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know if it is possible to do recursion with the commands from `xparse`? I would like to have a variable amount of arguments.

Comment: @EdgarPerner This seems an XY-problem. Please, clearly state your problem, not your (failing) attempt at a solution.

Comment: @EdgarPerner I provided a recursive version. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem.